# Как осуществить поиск по городам области при помощи Google Places Api for Android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api, google-places-api

Использую в своем проекте виджет службы подсказки мест по этому руководству:
https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete?hl=ru

Мне необходимо отфильтровать список городов только по одной области, например, поиск должен осуществляться только по городам московской области. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: можете передать параметром локацию центра Москвы и радиус поиска размером с Московскую область) но решение сомнительное